# exception: the object cannot be attached

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am trying to use entity framework by looping though all the records of the share table and update the price for each row:

```
public static void UpdateSharesPrices()
{
    foreach (var share in db.shares)
    {
        share.price=10;
        db.shares.Attach(share);
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(share, EntityState.Modified);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

the db.shares.Attach.. gives me an error though?

```
The object cannot be attached because it is already in the object context. An object can only be reattached when it is in an unchanged state.
```

How to do this or fix this?

Comment: Where do you instantiate `db`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying too hard. From my experience, this is all you need.

```
public static void UpdateSharesPrices()
{
    foreach (var share in db.shares)
    {
        share.price=10;
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```